# Что выполняет данная строка?

Tags: python

```
return '%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x' % (h0, h1, h2, h3, h4)
```

Comment: почитайте про форматирование строк (данный способ смахивает на С-шный printf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возвращает строку из перечисленных переменных, выведя каждую из них в формате `%08x`, т.е. в 16-ричном виде (`x`), на отображение каждой переменной отводится 8 разрядов, недостающие разряды дополняются нулями (`08`).

Comment: по-моему ссылка на документацию по форматированию строк могла бы помочь тем, кто попадет сюда из поисковиков )

Answer (score 3):

Дописывает кучу нулей ("0000000") перед значением каждой переменной (h0, h1, h2, h3, h4) объединяя их в одну строку и возвращает результат из функции.

Comment: Дописывает или дополняет до 8 знаков?

Comment: @Эникейщик А ну да. Поточнее будет.